# Varias condiciones en if PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una consulta en la cual traigo un valor desde la base de datos:

```
<?php
if($fila['uno'] <= 4) {
?>
```

Es simple, la que hace es alertar en color rojo si un valor es igual o menor a 4. El tema es que trato de hacer agregar mas datos al if y me da como resultado todos los valores en rojo.

```
<?php
if($fila['uno'] || $fila['dos'] || $fila['tres'] <= 4) {
?>
```

Esto es lo que hago y trate de hacer esto:

```
<?php
if($fila['uno'] & $fila['dos'] & $fila['tres'] <= 4) {
?>
```

Y me da como resultado los numero en negro sin poner en rojo los que son 4 y menores a 4

Comment: Una pregunta ¿tú quieres verificar si todos los valores en el array `$filas` son `<= 4` o sólo algunos valores dentro de él?

Comment: incluye el código de cada fila donde le pones "rojo" a cada una

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si cada valor debe cumplir la condición de ser <=4 para ser "rojo", hay que poner un `if` por cada valor, o como en este ejemplo un operador ternario en el `echo`.

Un operador ternario es un `if` disfrazado:

Si lo que está a la izquierda del `?` es verdadero (`true`) imprime el primer valor luego del `?`, en este ejemplo `'class="rojo"'`,

en cambio si es falso (`false`) imprime el valor que está después del `:`, en este caso `''` o sea... nada.

Algo así :

```
<td <?php echo ($fila['uno']<=4)?'class="rojo"':'' ?>><?php echo $fila['uno'];?></td>
<td <?php echo ($fila['dos']<=4)?'class="rojo"':'' ?>><?php echo $fila['dos'];?></td>
<td <?php echo ($fila['tres']<=4)?'class="rojo"':'' ?>><?php echo $fila['tres'];?></td>
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
<style>
  TD {text-align: center;padding:2px 5px;}
  .rojo {color:red;}
</style>
<?php
  $filas = [];
  $columnas = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'];
  for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) :
    $fila = [];
    foreach ($columnas as $col) :
      $fila[$col] = rand(1, 15);
    endforeach;
    $filas[] = $fila;
  endfor;
?>
<table>
<?php foreach ($filas as $fila) : ?>
  <tr>
<?php foreach ($columnas as $col) : ?>
    <td <?php echo ($fila[$col]<=4)?'class="rojo"':'' ?>><?php echo $fila[$col];?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

HTML generado por el ejemplo:

```
<style>
  TD {text-align: center;padding:2px 5px;}
  .rojo {color:red;}
</style>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="rojo">2</td>
        <td >8</td>
        <td class="rojo">4</td>
        <td >14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >12</td>
        <td >7</td>
        <td >13</td>
        <td >8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >6</td>
        <td >6</td>
        <td >12</td>
        <td >12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="rojo">4</td>
        <td class="rojo">2</td>
        <td >5</td>
        <td >8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >7</td>
        <td >6</td>
        <td >14</td>
        <td class="rojo">1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias alo Melbanez, `$filas = []; $columnas = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'];` esto es algo que no sabia y estaba tratando de hacer, pero no sabia como buscarlo!

Answer (score 0):

Tus condicionales estan incorrectos.  Para el efecto que deseas debes hacerlo asi:

```
<?php
  if($fila['uno'] <= 4 || $fila['dos'] <= 4 || $fila['tres'] <= 4) {
?>
```

Comment: Gracias Alanfcm, pero me sigue dando los resultados en rojo

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que solo aparescan rojos cuando las tres filas son menores que cuatro, entonces cambia los `||` por `&&`

Comment: si el rojo es por cada condición en cada fila hay que hacer varios if

Comment: Si es lo que pense hacer, porque no me el resultado que necesito. Voy a tener que hacer varios if

Comment: Estoy haciendo algo mal yo, por lo visto... `<?php
if($fila['uno'] <= 4 || $fila['dos'] <= 4 || $fila['tres'] <= 4) {
?>
<td><?=$fila['uno'];?></td>
<td><?=$fila['dos'];?></td>
<td><?=$fila['tres'];?></td>
<?php
} else {
?>
<td><?=$fila['uno'];?></td>
<td><?=$fila['dos'];?></td>
<td><?=$fila['tres'];?></td>
<?php
}
?>` porque le doy al td el color rojo y me los pone a todos del mismo color